# Collect results of multiple partial functions at single value?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, partialfunction

Suppose I have some partial functions that may have overlapping domains:

```
val funcs: Seq[PartialFunction[Any, Int]] = Vector(
{ case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i*2 }
,
{ case i: Int if i % 2 == 1 => i*3 }
,
{ case i: Int if i % 6 == 0 => i*5 }
)
```

I want to apply them to a value and collect the results for any that are defined at that val. I thought there would be an elegant way to use `collect` for this but the best I've been able to do is

```
val num = 66
funcs.collect { case func if func.isDefinedAt(num) => func(num) }
// or 
funcs.filter(_.isDefinedAt(num)).map(_(num))
```

This doesn't seem clean. Is there some way to use the builtin case mechanism to test definedness and evaluate at the same time, maybe by currying them against the test value or something like that?

Comment: What should be the behavior when two PFs overlap?  eg. What would you expect at `f(8)` ?

Comment: @maasg I don't think there's a need to combine the PFs. These are just separate PFs that should be called when they are defined at a specific value and the separate results should be aggregated in a list. (Also on a side note `8` is not a value where the overlap, but `66` is and the result there would be: `132, 130`)

Comment: I want both values -- this is why I'm defining this as a list of partial functions, rather than a single one with multiple `case`s (from what I understand it is not possible to get results from any matching cases beyond the first)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partial functions have a `lift` method that is `Some(res)` if the PF is defined and `None` if not defined. Also with the use of `flatMap` we can essentially ignore the `None`s and grab only the `Some` values.

```
funcs.flatMap { func => func.lift(num) }
```

Or compressed if you enjoy that sort of stuff:

```
funcs.flatMap(_.lift(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

> to test definedness and evaluate at the same time

That is `applyOrElse`. It's used by `collect` and `lift` to avoid the double-evaluation.

This recursive version says, Apply the next function and use it to build the result, or else just continue and build the rest of the result.

```
def f(ff: List[PartialFunction[Any, Int]]): List[Int] = ff match {
  case hd :: tail => hd.applyOrElse(num, (_: Any) => return f(tail)) :: f(tail)
  case _ => Nil
}
```

It's the first time I've ever used `return` in Scala. I had to look it up in the index.

This manual construction avoids some object creation in `Lifted`, the `Option` and adapting the `Option`.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val funcs: Seq[PartialFunction[Any, Int]] = Vector(
{ case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i*2 }
,
{ case i: Int if i % 2 == 1 => i*3 }
,
{ case i: Int if i % 6 == 0 => i*5 }
)
val num = 66

def f(ff: List[PartialFunction[Any, Int]]): List[Int] = ff match {
  case hd :: tail => hd.applyOrElse(num, (_: Any) => return f(tail)) :: f(tail)
  case _ => Nil
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

funcs: Seq[PartialFunction[Any,Int]] = Vector(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>)
num: Int = 66
f: (ff: List[PartialFunction[Any,Int]])List[Int]

scala> f(funcs.toList)
res0: List[Int] = List(132, 330)

scala> funcs flatMap (_ lift num)
res1: Seq[Int] = Vector(132, 330)
```

The second version just uses a flag for the same idea.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def f(ff: List[PartialFunction[Any, Int]]): List[Int] = ff match {
  case hd :: tail =>
    var ok = true
    val x  = hd.applyOrElse(num, (_: Any) => { ok = false ; 0 })
    if (ok) x :: f(tail) else f(tail)
  case _ => Nil
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

f: (ff: List[PartialFunction[Any,Int]])List[Int]

scala> f(funcs.toList)
res2: List[Int] = List(132, 330)
```